# Django pagination in TemplateView?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Django pagination in TemplateView?

Hello, I am trying to figure out how I can access multiple models in a Class View and paginate at the same time.

My Outcome after reading, DjangoDoc and Stackoverflow:

`ListView` - I simply can use `paginate_by=` but I can load only one Model.

`TemplateView` - I can load many models but can not use `paginate_by=`?

For example three Models: `Chicken`, `Cows` and `Cats` (and I want to display on my page the last 3 entries of each model). All Models have a model field called entry date.

```
class HomeIndex(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'home.html'
   paginate_by = 3 # --- something like that

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(HomeIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['chickens'] = Chicken.objects.order_by('-entry_date'')
      context['cows'] = Cows.objects.order_by('-entry_date'')
      context['cats'] = Cats.objects.order_by('-entry_date')

      return context
```

Or maybe I can add something to `objects.order_by('-entry_date', < pagination? >)`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django QuerySet has built-in results slicing.

```
 Cows.objects.order_by('-entry_date'')[offset:limit]
```

For the last 3 entries, offset is 0 and the limit 3

```
 Cows.objects.order_by('-entry_date'')[0:3]
```

or the same can be written in a more pythonic way

```
 Cows.objects.order_by('-entry_date'')[:3]
```

To get last 3 cows, cats and chicken, following code will work.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(HomeIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['chickens'] = Chicken.objects.order_by('-entry_date')[:3]
    context['cows'] = Cows.objects.order_by('-entry_date')[:3]
    context['cats'] = Cats.objects.order_by('-entry_date')[:3]


    return context
```

References:

- Limiting Queries [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `ListView` you still can, by chaining the querysets in `get_queryset(self)` and paginating that (read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434755/9848469) to see the `chain` and `sorted` explained). This way you can use the default simple pagination.

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import attrgetter

class HomeIndex(ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    paginate_by = 3 # --- somehting like that

    def get_queryset(self):
        chicken_list = Chicken.objects.all()
        cow_list = Cows.objects.all()
        cat_list = Cats.objects.all()

        result_list = sorted(
            chain(chicken_list, cow_list, cat_list),
            key=attrgetter('entry_date'),
            reverse=True)

        return result_list
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for data in object_list %}
    {{ data }} 
{% endfor %}
```

And you can use the pagination as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22919273/9848469).

Comment: Interesting approach. Useful also for other cases. I tried to access the result_list via regular {% for data in result_list %}  {{ data }} {% endfor %} but so far nothing shows up`?

Comment: Try accessing `{% for data in object_list %}` that is the default name for accessing the data from the template. Then you could use the default pagination object. I will update the answer.